# Have any Mark Brandis novels ever been released in English?

Tags: translation, mark-brandis

[Mark Brandis](http://www.markbrandis.de/) is both the main character as well as the nom de plume of the author [Nikolai von Michalewsky](http://www.vonmichalewsky.de/). The series was extremely popular in Germany in the '70s, and 31 volumes were published between 1969 and 1987.

There have been rumours of an English translation, but, [as you can see](http://www.markbrandis.wurzeldiener.net/index.php/%C3%9Cbersetzungen), I haven't been able to track one down.

(Sorry, all links point to German websites - there's no English language sites I know of ;-))

Comment: He doesn't seem to be referenced on [ISFDB](http://www.isfdb.org/), so probably not.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, you can read about Nikolai von Michalewsky/Mark Brandis in English by going [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mark_Brandis). No, the books never seem to have been translated into English, which is strange since von Michalewsky was considered one of the best-selling German science fiction authors of all time.  @Gilles has mentioned in a comment that his works are not listed on ISFDB, nor are any of them available in English through [Amazon.com](http://www.amazon.com/Mark-Brandis/e/B00455DMGK/ref=ntt_athr_dp_pel_1) (all the copies listed are available in German). Some of his works were, however, translated into Danish, Dutch, French, Italian, Spanish and Chinese.

---

Now you've peaked my interest and I want to read something of his to find out what made him so saleable in Germany!

Answer (score 4):

The Mark Brandis books have been written ABOUT in English, but as stated before, a no show @ISFDB means there most likely never existed an English translation.

I guess they were so popular because the hero is quintessentially (North-)German — that is: committed to larger causes, pedantic, well-organized — while strictly individualistic and humanistic. Therefore readers could identify with him without being labeled "nazi fans" by others. Brandis is also a faulted hero with a serious flirt with the bottle, and that made him endearing in a way (no super hero qualities — and certainly not a square-jawed space adventurer, member of the world science council chasing bad guys with a plucky sidekick).

Comment: I don't think any characteristics of the content or the hero were particularly unique. There probably just wasn't much SF available in German at the time, other than Perry Rhodan.